# Managing date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I'm a total noob in Python and I'm currently reading a script provided by a colleague. I got confused with the below script having it run today.

```
import datetime

today=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=4)
print (today)

if today.weekday() in [range(0,7)]:
    saturday=today-datetime.timedelta(today.weekday()-5)
    sunday=today-datetime.timedelta(today.weekday()-6)
else:
    saturday=today-datetime.timedelta(today.weekday()+2)
    sunday=today-datetime.timedelta(today.weekday()+1)

print (saturday)
print (sunday)
print (today.weekday())
```

Below is the result:

```
2018-07-19
2018-07-14
2018-07-15
3
```

Why is the script executing the one in `else`-statement? 
The `today.weekday()` results to 3 which should've executed the `if`-statement since 3 is within the range which if manually computed saturday = 2018-07-21.

Kindly advise where I have it understood incorrectly.

Comment: Using the correction from @Piotrek or @ThatBird, please note that `today.weekday() in range(0,7)` will always evaluate to `True` so the else statement is not reachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line -

```
if today.weekday() in [range(0,7)]
```

`range()` already gives you a list but in this case, it is a list of list and you get something like -

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

And as you see, `3 is not in [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

But if it were something like -

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3] #then it would have been true
```

Remove the brackets and make it this -

```
if today.weekday() in range(0,7)
```

And it should work

Comment: Hi! Thank you for explaining this to me. If I proceed with your instruction, when will the above script execute the else statement? Isn't each day assigned an integer from 0 to 7? If so, it will always execute the if statement, right?

Comment: @Janine you are right. It won't go in else statement

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if today.weekday() in [range(0,7)]:
```

to:

```
if today.weekday() in range(0,7):
```

and it will work properly.